# Can not find the icc compiler after having installed Intel oneAPI, invoking from bash on Ubuntu 20

Tags: icc, intel-oneapi

My problem is that I want to invoke the `icc` compiler from the command line, but my pc can't find it. I installed the latest oneAPI and sourced `setvars.sh`.

I even search for the `icc` file under the installation folder and I can't find the `icc` compiler file.

The `which` command works for `mpicc` and `dpcpp` but not for `icc`:

[image: can not find icc]

[image: mpicc found but not icc]

Comment: icl not icc. And icl/icc is deprecated anyway, "old" version Version 2021.8.0 Build 20221119_00000

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like you might have installed **Intel OneAPI base toolkit**. The icc compiler is not a part of the base toolkit. To get **icc**(Intel® C++ Compiler Classic) you should install **Intel OneAPI HPC toolkit**. Below is a link to HPC toolkit. You would see icc in the "whats included" section

https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/tools/oneapi/hpc-toolkit.html

You could install hpc toolkit on the top of your basekit, it installs only whatever is not present as a part of base toolkit.

Comment: I installed intel-hpckit and still don't have icc. Maybe it was removed in newer versions?

Comment: icc (as opposed to icx) is deprecated, yes. https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-oneAPI-IoT-Toolkit/DEPRECATION-NOTICE-Intel-C-Compiler-Classic/m-p/1412267

Answer (score 2):

`icc` is the "classic" compiler:

```
apt install intel-oneapi-compiler-dpcpp-cpp-and-cpp-classic
```

Comment: wget https://apt.repos.intel.com/intel-gpg-keys/GPG-PUB-KEY-INTEL-SW-PRODUCTS.PUB &&
sudo apt-key add GPG-PUB-KEY-INTEL-SW-PRODUCTS.PUB && 
echo "deb https://apt.repos.intel.com/oneapi all main" >/etc/apt/sources.list.d/intel-oneapi.list &&
apt-get update &&
apt-get install intel-oneapi-compiler-dpcpp-cpp-and-cpp-classic